# GETPIVOTDATA and Other Worksheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am having issues with extracting pivot table from another worksheet. I believe my syntax is wrong, but after trying several different renditions, nothing is correct.

here is what I have

```
 =Getpivotdata('Other WorkSheet'!$A$1 "Count of SOMETHING", $A$1)
```

I think my issue is with the absolute cell reference in the direction to the other sheet. However my search for answers has turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going back to the drawing board as I felt that I wasn't entering the formula in correctly. I should've posted this yesterday but I got tied down into something. The problem was how I was directing the formula to find the pivot table in question. The reference to the other worksheet should have been in the part of the formula that tells excel where the pivot table is. Here is the correct syntax:

```
 =getpivotdata("Count of SOMETHING", 'Other Worksheet'!$A$1)
```

Basically I had it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong exactly?  You don't need to type in the function, simply click the cell you want and Excel will create the function for you.